# How to create an 'read more' that shortens an article and links to the main page?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript and HTML, how do I create a 'read more' button to shorten an article?

When clicked, it should take me to the article on the very page where it was posted.

Comment: Are you using a server side language like PHP to create the HTML?  Or is this all static HTML?

Comment: In order to get the ball rolling for finding some proper help you should include any relevant code you've tried and are having issues with.

Comment: It's all static HTML

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO. It might be salvageable if you can show the HTML you've tried. Without a web framework, the idea is you have a main page that has short versions with a link, and the link goes to a new page with all the content. How you organize this is up to you and unknown to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to start with you can create and html file and write the following.

```
<div id = "blog">

</div>
```

In your javascript file use this code. Modify as per your requirement

```
var text = "this is very very very very long text";
var threshold = 10;
if(text.length <= threshold){
   document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = text.substring(0,threshold);
   var read_more = document.createElement("href");
   read_more.href = "www.linktomainpage.com";
   read_more.innerHTML = "Read More";
   document.getElementById("blog").appendChild(read_more);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out tonight.